# yii bootstrap navbar inline form

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I'm new at yii and I found what bootstrap can do.. so i thought to make an navigation bar with an inline form for the login. but I dont find how to do it..

Heres the code main layout:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar',array(
'type'=>'inverse',
'items'=>array(
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
            array('label'=>'Test', 'url'=>array('test/test')),
            array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
            array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),    //  Bottons appears at the right side of the Navigation Bar.
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
            array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
        ),
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

where "`bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu`" is, i want it to be an inline form like its shown in this [page](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbActiveForm), for now its just redirecting to login page,

I tried but it gives me error.. anyone knows how to do this? if not. any other way to do this please tell me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form inside TbNavbar Dropdown Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609834/form-inside-tbnavbar-dropdown-items)

Comment: Maybe this post leads to a solution

[form-inside-tbnavbar-dropdown-items][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609834/form-inside-tbnavbar-dropdown-items