# add badge to TbMenu in yiibooster

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

i want to add extra static html tag in TbMenu in NavBar Like This :

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
'type' => 'inverse',
'brand' => 'company',
'brandUrl' => Yii::app()->getHomeUrl(),
'collapse' => true,
'items' => array(
    array(
        'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
        'items' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Panel',
                'url' => '#',
                'items' => array(
                    array('label' => 'Inbox', 'url' => '#'),
                    '<span class="badge badge-important nav">2</span>',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'pull-left'),
    ),
),
```

));

want to show Unreaded Message In Navbar In Front of Inbox !

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: want to show badge in dropdown Menu in NavBar in Bootstrap, I use YiiBooster in Yii Framework .

Comment: You can't add `html` to `TbMenu`, but you can add it to `TbNavbar` as stated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14609834/form-inside-tbnavbar-dropdown-items/14615643#14615643